# Pyglet TextEntry not Working

Tags: python, pyglet

I have been trying to make a simple game, and have recently been trying to work on a menu system for it. I am trying to insert a TextEntry box using the examples they have provided themselves.

I have attempted to replicate their code, however I cannot enter any text with the TextEntry. The other widgets work fine, it is just this one. I am unsure if I need to call it into focus, but there does not appear to be any way to do so.

The relevant code is as such:

```
import pyglet


window = pyglet.window.Window(540, 500, caption="Widget Example")
batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
pyglet.gl.glClearColor(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0)


@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    batch.draw()


def text_entry_handler(text):
    text_entry_label.text = f"Text: {text}"

frame = pyglet.gui.Frame(window, order=4)

text_entry = pyglet.gui.TextEntry("Enter Your Name", 100, 100, 150, batch=batch)
frame.add_widget(text_entry)
text_entry.set_handler('on_commit', text_entry_handler)
text_entry_label = pyglet.text.Label("Text: None", x=300, y=100, batch=batch, color=(0, 0, 0, 255))

pyglet.app.run()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you input text when the mouse is above the text entry?
When the mouse is moved away from the text entry it wil stop accept input?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me. I can highlight single or all words with dbl- or triple-click, can delete with Bkspc or Del, etc. There are definitely some quirks though, where things just stop working until you use the mouse. I wonder what version of pyglet you were using, and whether there have been some updates/fixes since then?

Comment: Thanks for your question. I had no idea Frames were a thing. Even searching Google for "pyglet frame" only turns up stuff about frame rates.